# How to export a table with dash-lines

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-table

The following org file :

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{arydshln} % Draw dash-lines in array/tabular environments
| / | <      | <>    |
|---+--------+-------|
|   | Name   | Value |
|---+--------+-------|
|   | John   |    12 |
|   | Jane   |    10 |
|   | Jordan |     5 |
|   | Jack   |    15 |
|   | Jill   |     4 |
|   | Joe    |    13 |
|   | James  |    19 |
|---+--------+-------|
```

produces the following table when exported to tex.

```latex
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
\hline
Name & Value\\
\hline
John & 12\\
Jane & 10\\
Jordan & 5\\
Jack & 15\\
Jill & 4\\
Joe & 13\\
James & 19\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

How could I modify the org file in order to produce the following table (\hdashline is part of  arydshln latex package)?

```latex
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|r|}
\hline
Name & Value\\
\hline
John & 12\\\hdashline[.4pt/2pt]
Jane & 10\\\hdashline[.4pt/2pt]
Jordan & 5\\\hdashline[.4pt/2pt]
Jack & 15\\\hdashline[.4pt/2pt]
Jill & 4\\\hdashline[.4pt/2pt]
Joe & 13\\\hdashline[.4pt/2pt]
James & 19\\\hdashline[.4pt/2pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Simplest is to use a [filter](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Advanced-Export-Configuration): it's ad-hoc and very specialized to a particular case, but it's easy to implement *if* you can come up with a regex to do a search-and replace. Another way is to override the function that transcodes the table rows  (probably `org-latex-table-row`) to do what you want: that's also easy but it's pervasive: you will probably want to restore the original function after you are done with your file. A third way which is a bit more work but it can be used selectively is to write a derived back end ...

Comment: The derived back end (derived from the `LaTeX` backend) just overrides  the `table-row` function with a new one. The additional work is some boilerplate code to add the new backend to the export dispatch menu. The advantage is that you can use the new backend for the file above, but the original LaTeX backend is still present and can be used for most other situations.

Comment: I was looking for a simple and ad hoc solution indeed. Unfortunately, I don't see how I could use a regex. Also, I'm not able to fully understand the documentation (https://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-LaTeX-export.html) due to the lack of examples...

Comment: Could you provide an example of a filter that would add `\\\hdashline[.4pt/2pt]` (even if the input table is not the same the one provided in the example)? So I could better understand the filter mechanism, and especially with tables (would it start with `#+BIND: org-export-filter-table-functions`?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified filter, based on the one in the [doc](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Advanced-Export-Configuration):

```el
  (defun my-latex-filter-table-row (text backend info)
      "Modify the row as specified. Skip the modification on the header (matched with \"Name\" and hlines."
    (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)
      (if (or (string-match "Name" text) (string-match "hline" text))
          text
        (replace-regexp-in-string (concat (regexp-quote "[0pt]") "$") " \\hdashline[.4pt/2pt]" text nil t))))


  (add-to-list 'org-export-filter-table-row-functions
               'my-latex-filter-table-row)
```

For whatever reason, my entries before the filter is applied have a `[0pt]` at the end of each row of the table[1], which you don't seem to get, so you may have to play a bit with the first argument of `replace-regexp-in-string`. I presume that just `"$"` instead of the `(concat ...)` form would work in your case. It works for me, so other than that, it should work for you.

**EDIT**: The simplified `(replace-regexp-in-string  "$" " \\hdashline[.4pt/2pt]" text nil t)` works in my case (and I believe it will work in your case as well). The additional `[0pt]` that I have in my output does not seem to make any difference.

Note that the header line of the table and the `hline`s are tested for separately, so they will be left untouched. If you want to do this to multiple tables, you will have to check the header lines of each table with `(string-match "foo\|bar\|baz")` where `foo` and `bar` and `baz` are unique matches for each header line.

As you mention in your comment, you could use `#+BIND` instead of doing the `add-to-list` in the code block:

```
#+BIND: org-export-filter-table-row-functions (my-latex-filter-table-row)
```

The advantage is that you don't modify the global value of `org-export-filter-table-row-functions`: it is done locally and only for the duration of the export. `#BIND` is off by default however, so you will need to enable it by setting `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` to `t`.

Do `C-c C-c` on the code block and then export normally. To delete the filter, do something like this:

```el
#+begin_src elisp
(setq org-export-filter-table-row-functions
   (delete 'my-latex-filter-table-row
            org-export-filter-table-row-functions))
#+end_src
```

As I said, ad-hoc and very specialized - but it works.

---

[1] That's because in my version of Org mode (9.6.1 - release_9.6.1-236-gc8a5fe), `org-latex-table-row` ends the row by appending the value of the variable `org-latex-line-break-safe` which is `"\\\\[0pt]"` by default. This was changed last October: it prevents some pathological situations better than the previous default.See [commit b93a61af9c93d21c56cf883630e52f36076e40bd](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=b93a61af9c93d21c56cf883630e52f36076e40bd).

Comment: I modified your code a bit, with `(replace-regexp-in-string (concat (regexp-quote "\\\\") "$") "\\\\\\hdashline" text nil t)`. After evaluating the function, I tried to export to tex adding  `#+BIND` to org preamble but nothing happens, the usual tex is produced.

Comment: You should probably try it with the simplified `replace-regexp-in-string` and avoid changing anything: backslashes are a pain. For `#+BIND`, you need to enable it by setting `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` to `t` and you need to press `C-c C-c` on it in order to reinitialize the mode and let Emacs know that it's there.

Comment: `(setq org-export-allow-bind-keywords t)` made it work, thank you!

Comment: It's actually not necessary to do the `C-c C-c` bit, since on export the buffer is copied in its entirety to a temporary one and then the temp buffer is processed. But it's good to get in the habit of doing `C-c C-c` on a keyword whenever you add a new one: in almost all cases, it's necessary.